# Django send_mail SMTPSenderRefused 530 with gmail

Tags: python, django, gmail

I've been trying for some time to be able to receive emails with Django from a website I'm developing. Now, I haven't deployed it yet, and I am using the Django Development Server, and I don't know if this affects it.

Here is my settings.py configuration:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWROD = 'my_password'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Then, through the root folder of the project I run `python manage.py shell`, and type the following:

```
>>> import django
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> send_mail('test', 'test', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER], fail_silently=False)
```

And what I receive back is the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/paulo/anaconda3/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 62, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/home/paulo/anaconda3/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 348, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/paulo/anaconda3/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 111, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "/home/paulo/anaconda3/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 127, in _send
    self.connection.sendmail(from_email, recipients, message.as_bytes(linesep='\r\n'))
  File "/home/paulo/anaconda3/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 866, in sendmail
    raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthErrorv11sm8729581qkl.88 - gsmtp', 'my_email@gmail.com')
```

I have enabled the option to allow less secure applications.

I tried, when using 2-step verification, to input, instead of EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "my_password", to input EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'myapplicationpassword' provided by google. It didn't work.

Then I have disabled the 2-step verification and changed from the application password back to my actual password, and the error remains.

Am I doing something wrong? Has Google somehow blocked these types of application? Would I do better if I ran my own mail server?

Comment: Can you send mail with these settings via some other mail client? Also take a look at https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you do the following two things:

1. Go to [App passwords](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords) for 2-factor authentication, or look into "Less secure app access" if you're not using MFA. The password google provides when setting up as is a 16 digit code that includes spaces, they count.

[image: Custom app]
[image: generated password]

2. Make sure the settings imported or password set and/or retrieved is in the same terminal shell:

   ```
   EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD')

   export EMAIL_PASSWORD="xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx"
   ```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Google SMTP, Google has introducted a new security feature which blocks use of SMTP directly. In order to use Google SMTP, you need to sign into your Google account and enable access to less secure app. This option os present under Security Checkup under My Account. See the screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem and the gmail setting you show is already on

Comment: My answer is about 1 year old. I think now you need to authorize the apps as well. I'll find out more and will get back to you.

Comment: @ShwetabhSharan Did you find any new solution?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to edit bash_profile, bashrc, zshrc, profile etc. and nothing worked. If the variables are returning "None" try this :

As mentioned in this link [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) create an .env file (preferably in the root directory of your project) and put your credentials into it. Then in settings.py (if you are using django), use the following code:

```
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

env_path = Path('Path to the .env file')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
```

Then access the variable using the following code and you should be fine:

> os.environ.get('var_name')