# Sending email in django

Tags: django, email

I am trying to send email in django. i followed django documentation(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#quick-example) But I am getting an error.
The error:

```
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError q1sm10062648pfk.132 - gsmtp', '*******nl@gmail.com')
```

I have configured less secure app from google account.

settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*****@gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_PASSWORD = '*****'
```

Comment: Have you gone through the troubleshooting steps at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError ? Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805056/django-send-mail-smtpsenderrefused-530-with-gmail

Comment: can you tell me why this error is giving??? I want to setup email backend for my django project.

Comment: how did you configure your email backend in settings.py?..

Comment: If you can include code from the emailing file, as well the relevant app settings info, it would be helpful.

Comment: @Jonas Please see the edited part

Comment: @Ben I have edited the settings part

Comment: @NextGenDigiTechV.O.F. it is simple, your login credentials are wrong.. https://support.google.com/mail/thread/5579215?hl=en

Comment: @Jonas where am I wrong? I think i have done exactly what your solution suggests. I have given PORT 587 for TLS and given email and it's account password

Comment: @NextGenDigiTechV.O.F. Have you tried creating and using the "App Password" method as opposed to the less-secure method? https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: Just noticing now, but based on your code, it looks like you are setting `EMAIL_USE_PASSWORD`, which should instead be: `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More likely your Django settings related to `smtp` mail are wrong. Check below settings in your Django app.

- EMAIL_HOST
- EMAIL_PORT
- EMAIL_HOST_USER
- EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD
- EMAIL_USE_TLS
- EMAIL_USE_SSL

P.S You don't need to set all those variables. Depends how `smtp` server is set up you might need to set only `EMAIL_HOST` and `EMAIL_PORT` without setting `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`

Comment: I was using [django-anymail](https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail) in my application -it worked well. Give it a go, maybe it will work for you as well.

Comment: What should I give in this part?  `ANYMAIL = {
    # (exact settings here depend on your ESP...)
    "MAILGUN_API_KEY": "<your Mailgun key>",
    "MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN": 'mg.example.com',  # your Mailgun domain, if needed
}` I have not any domain or mailgun key.

Comment: I recommend to create a [mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) account and use sandbox credentials.

Comment: I have created a mailgun account. where can I find the sandbox credentials?

Comment: read the [docs](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/203380100-Where-Can-I-Find-My-API-Key-and-SMTP-Credentials)

Comment: can I setup my own domain?

Comment: I believe you can do that

Comment: I can not see any option for adding domain. Do I need to pay for that?

Comment: Don't know that read the docs and follow tutorial that mailgun provides. My help ends here.

Comment: I did not use anymail. But it is working. Do i need anymail?

Comment: The short answer is no.